# Has there ever been a two engine Air Carrier where both engines failed during the takeoff run resulting in an accident?

Tags: takeoff, accidents, engine-failure, accident-statistics

Has there ever been a two engine Air Carrier anywhere that has had both engines fail at some point during the takeoff run that resulted in an accident?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing when researching for [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/90345/33692). I couldn't find one, but it's hard to prove a negative...

Comment: @Bianfable Ameristar Charters Flight 9363 is one where it was aborted after VR, not due to engine failure but a jammed elevator.

Comment: I found several single engine failures during takeoff that resulted in crashes like AA191, several aborted takeoffs with blown tires or tires on fire after dual failures, some with runway excursions, but no serious accidents. Animal strike list for past 30 years: https://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/wildlife/media/significant-wildife-strikes-1990-jan-2021.pdf&clen=3281418&chunk=true

Comment: @raft can you give more info (e.g. link or similar) on the tire fires or blown tires that resulted in a ruway excursion? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Checking SKYbrary's runway excursion [article](https://skybrary.aero/articles/runway-excursion) and [reports](https://skybrary.aero/articles/accident-and-serious-incident-reports-re), and the FAA's [Lessons Learned](https://lessonslearned.faa.gov/ll_main.cfm?TabID=3&CategoryID=22), and checking the ones involving a takeoff, I could not find **any** that match the criteria in the question.

---

The one I can think of that is arguably related: during the takeoff segment of a training touch-and-go aboard an Airbus A320 [in 2018](https://avherald.com/h?article=4b57c3dd), an impressive chain of events led to a failed elevator and early gear retraction, and then both engines hit the runway, ultimately failing in the air, but they didn't fail *on the runway.* The crew managed to turn back, crash land, and survive.

Comment: Interesting, but both engines ultimately failed during the aircraft's final approach when returning to land apparently after being damaged during the takeoff incident. Thanks for the research.

Comment: @757toga: copy; see update.

Comment: I also could not find an accident after a 2-engine failure during the takeoff run. Interestingly,  in 1987, shortly after departing LAX in a B767,  the Capt. inadvertently shutdown both engines (pulled the fuel shutoff switches to off) over the water at about 1600 ft but the crew was able to restore power (restart) at about 600 ft above the water.

Answer (score 3):

This one is close, the first failure happened just past VR, second shortly after.  The aircraft only made it 15ft off the ground.

> On 9/1/2005 a DA-20 Falcon (Business Jet) was taking off from Lorain
> County Airport in Ohio.  Shortly after rotation, the aircraft hit a
> flock of birds, causing the #1 engine to flame out. As the gear was
> retracted, they hit another flock, which caused the #2 engine RPM to
> roll-back. The pilot was not able to sustain airspeed or altitude and
> crash-landed, sliding through a ditch and airport perimeter fence,
> crossing a road and ending in a corn field. Aircraft sustained major
> structural damage beyond economical repairs. Both pilots were taken to
> hospital. Only the copilot sustained minor injuries. The NTSB
> investigated, case # IAD05LA129. Costs totaled $1.4 million.

A second source says:

> The pilot was flying the airplane at takeoff, as the copilot monitored the flight instruments, and
> made "V" speed and rotation callouts. When the airplane was about 15 feet above the runway,
> birds flew up from both sides of the runway, and into both engines. The number two engine
> "surged," and made several "loud reports" before the copilot noted a complete loss of power on
> the number two engine instruments. The copilot announced the loss of power, and the pilot
> called for retraction of the landing gear.
> The airplane climbed for about 10 seconds, before the copilot observed the gas producer (N1)
> gauge on the number one engine decay through 50 percent. The stall warning horn sounded,
> and the pilot adjusted the flight controls for landing.
> The airplane contacted the runway "straight and level at approximately 130 knots," with the
> landing gear retracted, about 3,000 feet beyond the point of rotation. The airplane overran the
> runway, struck a fence, crossed a road, and came to rest in a cornfield about 1,000 feet beyond
> the initial point of ground contact

Sources:

https://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/wildlife/media/significant-wildife-strikes-1990-jan-2021.pdf

https://reports.aviation-safety.net/2005/20050901-0_FA20_N821AA.pdf

There is another business jet example in that wildlife strike PDF where they hit a deer and the thrust reversers failed (part of the engine) so they couldn't stop fast enough and crashed into a ditch past the runway.